# Installing extra RAM MacPro

Tags: mac, memory

I have early 2008 MacPro tower, OSX 10.6. It had 1x4G RAM in it. I purchased 4x4G extra RAM. In what sequence should I place them in the top and bottom trays to achieve a total of 20G?

Answer (score 3):

Apple provide a PDF for their official [Memory Replacement Instructions](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/MacPro_MemoryDIMM_DIY.pdf).

But to make it simple, your final positioning should be:

```
Riser A 
Slot Connector
DIMM (4G)
DIMM (4G)
DIMM (1G)
DIMM (1G)
Back of Riser (The end with a hole at the corners)

Riser B
Slot Connector
DIMM (4G)
DIMM (4G)
DIMM (1G)
DIMM (1G)
Back of Riser (The end with a hole at the corners)
```

Comment: Very informative PDF link :) it explains it very clear that memory installation should be done in pairs of same size and same brand. Since up to 4 pairs can be installed (8 DIMMS altogether) nothing seems to stop anyone from installing 2 times n-GBs of Brand A, 2 times m-GBs of Brand B... etc. Although gotta make sure the RAM is compatible with your system of course!